# ¿Cual es el tamaño máximo que puede tener una tabla en SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql-server

¿Cual es el tamaño máximo que puede tener una tabla en SQL Server 2014?
Me interesa saber el tamaño maximo para tratar de saber un estimado de cuando es necesario particionar una  tabla en SQL server

Comment: Es difícil de decir cuando es necesario de particionar una tabla, en la mayoría de los casos es recomendable de particionarla ya antes que sea técnicamente necesario.Te ayudan los [especificaciónes en español](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ES/library/ms143432.aspx)?

Comment: El titulo y contenido parecen ser 2 preguntas diferentes...

Comment: Esa especificación ya la vi y de hecho de ahí surgió la duda que tengo, ya que no dice nada al respecto. Y si parecen preguntas diferentes pero es el mismo tema, ya que van de la mano.

Comment: deberías cambiar el titulo de tu pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay ningún máximo. Si notas lo que dice la [documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms143432(v=sql.120).aspx):

> **Filas por tabla.** Limitado por el espacio de almacenamiento disponible.

O sea que, mientras haya espacio disponible, en teoría, una tabla puede seguir creciendo indefinidamente.

Comment: Ok, estoy de acuerdo, pero entonces ¿cual es el tamaño en que se debe empezar a particionar una tabla?

Comment: Eso ya es otra pregunta completamente, y una muy amplia además. No hay una regla de oro fijo que aplique a todas las situaciones. Depende de muchos factores: tipo de datos, la frecuencia a la que se insertan los datos, si existe una agrupación lógica de los datos, el tipo de consultas que necesitas hacer, etc... Te va a tocar abrir otra pregunta, y agregarle muchos detalles específicos en cuanto a tus datos y su uso para poder darte una respuesta acertada.